# How DO you add a check constraint to a postgresql materialised view?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6, materialized-views, check-constraints

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW chk__foo AS (
    SELECT 1
        FROM ...
        WHERE ...
    ) WITH DATA
;
```

Now check that there are no such entries

```
ALTER ??? ADD CONSTRAINT integrity_violated CHECK (0=1);
```

Doesn't seem to matter if I put `TABLE` or `MATERIALIZED VIEW` for `???`, I keep getting

> `chk__foo` is not a table or foreign table

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?  A check constraint on a materialized view doesn't really make sense.  Would an insert that violated the constraint be blocked in the base tables?  Or would the materialize view itself simply not be created?

Comment: @GordonLinoff the idea is to build a view that collects "invalid" data, so when we  `REFRESH` it, it should stay empty or else raise an exception.

Comment: Please check the answer for your [identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952825/whats-the-closest-we-can-get-to-refresh-complete-on-commit-in-postgresql).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thank you for your reply, but the questions -- although related in this particular use case -- are radically different. this one is "how to add a constraint", the other is "how to enforce trigger execution within same transaction". Your answer, granted, is the same: don't.

Comment: @GordonLinoff "A check constraint on a materialized view doesn't really make sense." It's my understanding that a materialized view in PostGres is much the same as a materialized view in Oracle — that is, it's a TABLE in its own right, though created with View syntax. As such, there's no reason that its relationships mirror that of any of the tables it depends on. In my case, I'm building a taxonomic hierarchy from tables that _don't_ have that hierarchy, and I'm going to be forced to use DELETE, CREATE, INSERT on a table.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a check constraint to a materialized view.

You can “roll it by hand” by creating a table and using `TRUNCATE` and `INSERT ... SELECT` to refresh the data.

Comment: The “roll it by hand” suggestion is no joke. In MySQL, not having an implementation of materialized views, that’s basically what I did. The caveat is that I also enforced currency with triggers, such that modifications to the base tables were propagated to the derivative table.